# Android emulator hosts file not working for android app

Tags: android, react-native, fetch, hosts-file

I have a react native app running on an android emulator and I'm trying to make a request to my local api(running on my laptop) at https://dev.mywebsite.com/api . This domain is host filed in the emulator like so :

`/etc/hosts` and `/system/etc/hosts` and `/etc/system/hosts` all have:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             ip6-localhost
10.0.2.2        dev.mywebsite.com
```

Note: I have also tried my local ip address of 192.168.1.13

The domain has a real ssl certificate and I'm able to access it from chrome on the emulator without issues.

Changing my api call to target https://mywebsite.com/api which is deployed in production does work.

Running `adb shell` and pinging `dev.mywebsite.com` shows 127.0.0.1 for some reason?

Why would chrome in the emulator work but my react native app doesn't? If you help me solve this I'll be so excited :) Maybe there's some workaround to this? I'll toss in a rep bounty.

### EDIT

I got it working on a physical device(not emulator). I used an app called "Hosts Go" to host file to 192.168.1.13 and it works. Why does the Hosts Go app work but the emulator hosts file doesn't? I wasn't able to edit the hosts file on my physical device as it's not rooted to test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if this isn't on the trickier problems to debug...

**Put a blank line at the end of your hosts file.**

Chrome for some reason works if your hosts file doesn't have it, but a request from your app won't.

Answer (score 2):

when not blank line at the end of my phone hosts file, my meizu_16s_android10 phone hosts is still working

but when I run `adb push 'C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts' '/etc/hosts'`

android hosts will be not working

I find windows use `CRLF`, android use `LF`

when i replace it, android hosts is working

Comment: Thank you, saving with a blank line at the end using `LF` fixed the issue for me as well!